# Last added element value reflected in whole list in python - How to solve this problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

The following is my data:

```
"Jay": 1, "Raj": 1,"Jay": 3,"Raj": 3,"Jay": 10,"Raj": 2,"Jay": 2
```

I would like to put it into a list to make it look like this:

```
["Jay": 1,"Raj": 1,"Jay": 3,"Raj": 3,"Jay": 10,"Raj": 2,"Jay": 2]
```

My issue is that only the final element is pushed to the entire list. The result looks like this:

```
["Jay": 2,"Raj": 2,"Jay": 2,"Raj": 2,"Jay": 2,"Raj": 2,"Jay": 2]
```

How would I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try using a **list of dictionary elements** and update an element like `list[<index>][<Name>] = <value>` 
:- example `list[3]["Raj"] = 4`

Answer (score 1):

tou use `dict` it has a `unique key value par properties` that why when you and new it will update last add key value par if not has any key it will add new key

> It will work on `list of list` if you do want replace last element then try  following way may be your problem solve

```
list_var = []
list_var.append(['Jay',1])
print(list_var) #[['Jay',1]]

#you can append list using append method so list is ordered collection so add another one

list_var.append(['Raj',1])
print(list_var) #[['Jay',1],['Raj',1]]

#add another
list_var.append(['Jay',3])
print(list_var) #[['Jay',1],['Raj',1],['Jay',3]]

#using for you will print
for name,score in list_var:
    print(name,score)

#or you will access by index
list_var[0] #[['Jay',1]
```

Or you can manipulate by **map filter reduce** method

Using this stuff may you understand if any problem let me know and if it's work then let me know

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `dict`, use `list` and `tuple` instead:

```
your_list = [ ('Jay', 1), ('Raj', 3), ('Jay', 1), ('Raj', 3) ]
```

When using `dict` you cannot use same keys.